# How to add extra language packs to WordPress

Tags: translation

I've got a multisite which I installed in Dutch.
Therefore English and Dutch are available in the general settings tab.
But I need to add German and French.
I can't select any other language from the drop down.

And if I add a language in the `wp-config.php` it just gives a notice without any direction.

Of course I googled but I can't seem to find anything useful.

How can I active an other language and download the `.PO`/`.MO` files?

- http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Localization
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The easiest way for me is to change language settings for main blog
       multiple times (as mach as many languages I need) and WordPress will
       load these languages automatically.
2. And after that I go to Update page and update language packages (loads languages for
   themes, plugins, etc.)

Comment: Yes WP will automatic download it when changing the lanuage settings. This was not the case back in 2014

Answer (score 7):

So what you should do is head over to https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/dev

And download the language `.mo` files, and copy them to your `wp-content/languages/` folder.

This should allow you to select other languages.

Comment: Where can I download? I don't see a link to a `.mo` or any files.

Comment: I see it now Below is an export

Comment: Now I see have DE and can select it from the dropdown but I still miss a lot and the updater does not see anything missing even after forcing it to check.

Answer (score 2):

To make it clearer:

- go to https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/dev (as explained by @Bordoni)
- choose your language
- scroll to the bottom of the page
- select export (both .po and .mo)
- put those files (rename them to the isocode, like fr_FR.po and fr_FR.mo) in wp-content/languages/

It felt complex to me to find that information somewhere in the standard WordPress documentation site.